# Concat Same Name different Value JSON object into unique one

Tags: java, arrays, json

When I tried this:

```
JSONObject xyz = new JSONObject();
JSONArray abc = new JSONArray();


while(rs.next())  
{    

    String a = rs.getString("enrollno");
    String b = rs.getString("name");
    xyz.put("no" , a);
    xyz.put("name" ,b); 

    abc.put(xyz);
    System.out.println(abc.toString());
}
```

outputs like:

```
[{"no":"IU121","name":"Heer"}]

[{"no":"IU12410500","name":"Ravi"},{"no":"IU12410500","name":"Ravi"}]

[{"no":"IU1241050050","name":"Rax"},{"no":"IU1241050050","name":"Rax"},{"no":"IU1241050050","name":"Rax"}]
```

But I want output like:

```
[{"no":"IU121","name":"Heer"},{"no":"IU12410500","name":"Ravi"},{"no":"IU1241050050","name":"Rax"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
while(rs.next())  
{    

String a = rs.getString("enrollno");
String b = rs.getString("name");
JSONObject xyz = new JSONObject();
xyz.put("no" , a);
xyz.put("name" ,b); 

abc.put(xyz);
System.out.println(abc.toString());
}
```

Comment: Patience, patience, @prasad.